# Red-black tree not matching performance of Java's TreeMap

Tags: java, performance, tree

This program is for constructing a symbol table where a key is a word and value is the frequency of the word in a text file and finding the word with maximum frequency.

I did it in two ways:

First I used Java's inbuilt `TreeMap`, which uses a red-black tree as internal data structure.

Then I made my own implementation of red-black tree and did the same thing.But I was lot disappointed when my program came whole lot slower in accomplishing the task. I ran both the programs several times. But still the minimum time of `TreeMap` was lesser than my own program time by at least 1 million of nano seconds. Also it won every time when I computed average time taken by both. This much time lag makes me ask whether I can improve my implementation of red-black tree about which I am really skeptical.

First method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class TREEMAP_APP
{
 public static void main(String []args)throws IOException
 {
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("book.txt"));
     TreeMap<String , Integer> tm = new TreeMap<String , Integer>();
     String S="";
     String []arr;
     String line;
     int max=0;
     long st=System.nanoTime();
     while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
     {
         arr=line.split(" ");

         for(String k:arr)
          if(!tm.containsKey(k))
           tm.put(k,1);
          else
          {
            tm.put(k,tm.get(k)+1);
            if(tm.get(k)>max)
            {S=k;max=tm.get(k);}
          }
     }
     long ft=System.nanoTime()-st;
     System.out.println("time taken is "+ft);
     System.out.println("the word that occurs for the maximum no of times is and it occurs for");
     System.out.println(S+"    "+max);
    }
}
```

Red-black tree:

```
import java.io.*;
class REDBLACK
{
 int max=0;String S="";
 public Node insert(Node x,String key)
 {
     if(x==null)
     {
         return new Node(key,1,'R',null,null);
     }
     else if(key.compareTo(x.key)>0)
     {
         x.right=insert(x.right,key);         
     }
     else if(key.compareTo(x.key)<0)
     {
         x.left=insert(x.left,key);         
     }
     else {x=new Node(key,x.value+1,x.color,x.left,x.right);}     

     if(isRed(x.right)&&!isRed(x.left))   x=rotate_left(x);
     else if(isRed(x.left)&&isRed(x.left.left)) x=rotate_right(x);
     else if(isRed(x.left)&&isRed(x.right)) flip_color(x);
     return x;     
 }
 public boolean isRed(Node x)
 {
     if(x==null) {return false;}
     if(x.color=='R')
     return true;
     else return false;
 }
 public Node rotate_left(Node x)
 {
     Node y=x.right;
     x.right=y.left;
     y.left=x;
     y.color=x.color;
     x.color='R';
     return y;
 }
 public Node rotate_right(Node x)
 {
     Node y=x.left;
     x.left=y.right;
     y.right=x;
     y.color=x.color;
     x.color='R';
     return y;
 }
 public void flip_color(Node x)
 {
     x.color='R';
     x.left.color='B';
     x.right.color='B';
 }
 public static void main(String []args)throws IOException
 {
   REDBLACK tree1=new REDBLACK();
   Node root=null;
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("book.txt"));   
   String []arr;
   String line;
   int max=0;
   long st=System.nanoTime();
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
   {
       arr=line.split(" ");
       for(String s:arr)
        root=tree1.insert(root,s);       
   }
   long ft=System.nanoTime()-st;
     System.out.println("time taken is "+ft);
   System.out.println("the word with maximum freq is "+Node.S+" and its freq is "+Node.max);   
 }
 public void iot(Node x)
 {
     if(x==null)
      return;
     iot(x.left);
     System.out.println(x.key+" "+x.value);
     iot(x.right);     
 }
}

class Node
{
 String key;int value;char color;
 Node left,right;static int max=0;static String S="";
 Node(String key,int value,char color,Node l,Node r)
 {
     this.key=key;
     if(value>max)
     {max=value;S=key;}
     this.value=value;
     this.color=color;
     this.left=l;
     this.right=r;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us the contents of book.txt?  When I ran your two programs, the red black tree version was faster than the TreeMap version.

Comment: @JS1 a text file containing 700 to 800 words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My own tests

I ran your program with various inputs, and in all my tests, your red black tree was faster than the TreeMap version.  I even fixed the TreeMap version so that it wouldn't search up to three times for the same word:

```
        Integer val;
        arr=line.split(" ");

        for(String k:arr) {
            val = tm.get(k);
            if (val == null) {
                tm.put(k,1);
            } else {
                int newVal = val + 1;
                tm.put(k, newVal);
                if (newVal > max) {
                    S = k;
                    max = newVal;
                }
            }
        }
```

With the above change, the TreeMap version is about 10% slower than your red black tree.  It makes sense that the red black tree version would be faster because in the TreeMap version, you have a `get` followed by a `put` for each string.  In your red black tree version, you only have one `insert` which performs both functions.

### Comments on your code

There were several places where I thought you squished your code when you didn't have to.  For example:

> ```
>  else {x=new Node(key,x.value+1,x.color,x.left,x.right);}     
>
>  if(isRed(x.right)&&!isRed(x.left))   x=rotate_left(x);
>  else if(isRed(x.left)&&isRed(x.left.left)) x=rotate_right(x);
>  else if(isRed(x.left)&&isRed(x.right)) flip_color(x);
> ```

and

> ```
> Node left,right;static int max=0;static String S="";
> ```

I feel like you should space your code out and keep your statements on separate lines from the `if` and `else`.

### Improvement to red black tree

In your red black tree code, where you have this:

> ```
>  else {x=new Node(key,x.value+1,x.color,x.left,x.right);}
> ```

it could be faster if you don't allocate a new node and instead modify the current one.  Also, you could make the insert faster by only calling the comparison function once.  Here is a rewrite of your `insert()` function that makes your program about 10% faster than before:

```
public static int max;
public static String S;
public Node insert(Node x,String key)
{
    if (x == null) {
        if (max == 0) {
            max = 1;
            S = key;
        }
        return new Node(key,1,'R',null,null);
    }
    int comparison = key.compareTo(x.key);
    if (comparison > 0) {
        x.right = insert(x.right,key);
    } else if (comparison < 0) {
        x.left = insert(x.left,key);
    } else {
        x.value++;
        if (x.value > max) {
            max = x.value;
            S = key;
        }
    }
    if (isRed(x.right) && !isRed(x.left)) {
        x = rotate_left(x);
    } else if (isRed(x.left) && isRed(x.left.left)) {
        x = rotate_right(x);
    } else if (isRed(x.left) && isRed(x.right)) {
        flip_color(x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

### Try HashMap instead

What I think you are missing is that a `HashMap` is faster than both the TreeMap and the red black tree.  I replaced the `TreeMap` with a `HashMap` and the result was about 50% faster than the TreeMap and about 25% faster than the improved red black tree.

Comment: I don't know what to say, but in my case the opposite is happening,Please take a large file.

Comment: @Dante Try using a HashMap and see if it makes it even faster?  I tried using a many MB file and the results were the same.

Comment: I need some help from you in analyzing the time complexity.

Comment: Its not related to this question.

Comment: Are you willing to help.

Comment: @Dante Why not post a new question?  If it's not a code review, then maybe on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Kindly see my profile second question.